# Parameter transformation from string to array to json in Azure Pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

The desire is actually quite simple. A string parameter should be converted to a JSON string.

```
SOURCE: "Feature_A;Feature_B"
TARGET: [{"name":"Feature_A","value":"true"},{"name":"Feature_B","value":"true"}]
```

I was hoping to use the correct expression functions to do the conversion. Unfortunately, I have not found this yet.

```
steps:
  - pwsh: |
      #############################################################################
      $featureAsJson = "$env:FEATUREFLAGS_AS_JSON";
      #############################################################################

      Write-Host "feature-flag-to-json:";
      Write-Host $featureAsJson;
      [Environment]::Exit(0);
    displayName: "TEST AUSGABE"
    env:
      FEATUREFLAGS_AS_JSON: ${{ join(',', split(parameters.featureFlags, ';')) }}
```

Is there a proper expression function that converts individual items of an array? Comparable to the following C# code:

```cs
void Main()
{
  var list = new []{"Feature_A", "Feature_B"};
  var newList = list.Select(item=> $"{{\"name\":\"{item}\",\"value\"=\"true\"}}");
  var json = string.Join(",", newList);
  json = $"[{json}]";
  Console.WriteLine(json); // => [{"name":"Feature_A","value":"true"},{"name":"Feature_B","value":"true"}]
}
```

*Background of my question:*

I would like to specify a simple semicolon separated list of feature flags as a user of an Azure Devops YML pipeline. This list should be written to a config file using a single task. The content of the task/template is already predefined and is very difficult to change. Using the well-known each-loop, this already works very well:

```
- ${{ each flag in split(parameters.featureFlags, ';')}}:
   - template: edit-json-file.yml
     parameters:
       jsonPath: ${{ parameters.jsonPath }}
       settings:
         - name: ${{ flag }}
           value: "true"
```

However, a separate task is put for every single feature flag. And exactly this bothers me a bit. It would be cooler to use the right expression functions to process the feature flags as JSON and then pass them to the template.

```
- template: edit-json-file.yml
  parameters:
    jsonPath: ${{ parameters.jsonPath }}
    settings: $ {{ ??? }}
```

Comment: What type does settings parameter have? How it is used in template?

Comment: The parameter has the type `object` in the template. And is processed with the help of the expression function `convertToJson(..)` within the template. However, I can adjust the template so that `settings` is also of type `string`. Then only the mentioned text conversion from a simple semicolon separated list into a matching JSON string remains.